# How to generate the following Dataset to plot in 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graphics, matplotlib-3d

I have been trying for around 2 days now to create the 2 half-moons data set in 3 dimensions.

First, I did it in two dimensions, and this link is very helpful for understanding how to plot the data set: [Creating a dataset in the form of two half semi circle arcs in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51824188/creating-a-dataset-in-the-form-of-two-half-semi-circle-arcs-in-python)

Then, I decided to try 3 dimensions. The way to do this would be to think of the shape as a tube that is bent, and this tube is composed of a lot of thin disks. In each of these disks, we take a uniform random number of points, which this link is very useful for: [Generate a random point within a circle (uniformly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly/50746409#50746409)

After this, I need to rotate and translate these disks, but this is what I am stuck on and would appreciate any help. If you are unable to help and provide code or explanation for this, another approach could also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Then, I decided to try 3 dimensions. The way to do this would be to think of the shape as a tube that is bent

Seems like you are trying to generate random points inside the volume of a torus (or half a torus). Instead of following your approach (a series of disks), I suggest a different one. First, you need to [parameterize the torus](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torus.html).

Then, you need to generate the [random distribution of points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly/50746409#50746409).

Let's put the pieces together. I'm going to use Plotly as it has an equal aspect ratio for 3d plots. Obviously, you can also apply offsets to the dataset.

```py
import numpy as np

def random_dist_torus(a, c, n_low=1000, n_high=10000):
    """
    Parameters
    c: radius from the center of the hole to the center of the torus
    a: radius of the tube
    n_low: minimum number of points in the volume
    n_high: maximum number of points in the volume
    """
    n = int(np.random.uniform(n_low, n_high))
    # consider a cross section of the torus, which is going
    # to be a circle. The variable r represents the radius
    # of the points in this cross section.
    r = a * np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
    # u: angular coordinate of the torus. Here I set it
    # to np.pi, so it will generate only half torus
    u = np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
    # v: circumferential coordinate. Consider a cross section
    # of a torus, which is going to be a circle. v represents
    # the angle around this circle.
    v = 2 * np.pi * np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
    return (
        (c + r * np.cos(v)) * np.cos(u), # x-coordinates
        (c + r * np.cos(v)) * np.sin(u), # y-coordinates
        r * np.sin(v)  # z-coordinates
    )


import plotly.graph_objects as go

x1, y1, z1 = random_dist_torus(2, 4)
x2, y2, z2 = random_dist_torus(2, 4)
fig = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x1, y=y1, z=z1,
            mode='markers',
            marker=dict(
                size=2,
            )
        ),
        go.Scatter3d(
            x=x2, y=-y2, z=z2,
            mode='markers',
            marker=dict(
                size=2,
            )
        )
    ])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What do `u`, `v`, and `r` represent?

Comment: I updated the answer (see the comments in the code). Also, you can play with the parameters to fully understand what they achieve.

Comment: So where do you use the random distribution of points: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837572/generate-a-random-point-within-a-circle-uniformly/50746409#50746409

Comment: You can see that in the code: each point is parameterized by `r, u, v`. These variables uses a random distribution of values (look for `np.random.uniform`). So, in the cross-section plane, each point has a random radius `r` and a random circumferential direction `v`. They also have a random angular position `u` along the torus.

Comment: How can I make this so that this is like a perfectly cylindrical tube?
This torus is very "tall" and is not a perfect cylindrical shape. How can I make it so that it is like a donut (where the cross sections are perfect circles)?

Comment: You can play with the parameters `a` and `c` when calling `random_dist_torus(a, c)`. For example, you can increase `c` (the radius of the torus) and decrease `a` (the radius of the tube).